# .Push with Multidimensional Arrays Exceeding a Two Column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I could use a little assistance figuring out how `.push` works with `Multidimensional Arrays`. I am writing a simple program that gathers information from cells in a `Google Sheets` page and the automatically generating a list of columns that need to be updated and sending an email to the team for visibility. I am transitioning back to `JavaScript` from `VB.Net` so I keep wanting to use methods I would use in VB. I have read through several posts on here, but can't seem to wrap my head around it. The way I visualize 2D arrays is like a spread sheet, but in the examples I found it does not quite visualize with me the same.

[Employee Name] [Status] [Start Date]

I see the above as `empRec[0,0]` `empRec[0,1]` `empRec[0,2]`

But in the push examples I see `empRec.push({"Employee Name", "Status"});`

Am I to understand that the `,` separates the values in the second value? Would adding another `,` and a value shift to position 2 in the second value?

Thank you for the input in advanced.

> Code Snip

```
// Extract the users who need review
for (r=2; r <= eName.length - 1; r++) {

if (eName[r] != "") {

  if (eAcceptNDA[r] == "" || eAvailability[r] == "" || eType[r] == "" || eDays[r] == "") {
    mailRecList[mailRecCount, 0] = eName[r];

    if (eAcceptNDA[r] == "") {
      mailRecList[mailRecCount, 1] = "Needed";
    } else { mailRecList[mailRecCount, 1] = "----"; }

    if (eAvailability[r] == "") {
      mailRecList.push[mailRecCount, 2] = "Needed";
    } else { mailRecList[mailRecCount, 2] = "----"; }

    if (eType[r] == "") {
      mailRecList[mailRecCount, 3] = "Needed";
    } else { mailRecList[mailRecCount, 3] = "----"; }

    if (eDays[r] == "") {
      mailRecList[mailRecCount, 4] = "Needed";
    } else { mailRecList[mailRecCount, 4] = "----"; }

    Logger.log(mailRecList[mailRecCount, 0] + ", " + mailRecList[mailRecCount, 1] + ", " + mailRecList[mailRecCount, 2] + ", " + mailRecList[mailRecCount, 3] + ", " + mailRecList[mailRecCount, 4]);
    Logger.log(mailRecList.length / 5);

  }
  mailRecCount += 1;
}
  }
```

When I run the above code it only returns a single row. There are 3 values currently in the sheet and it only returns the last value. The reason the `for loop` begins with 2 is because the first 2 values are header information on the sheet.

Comment: In this line: `mailRecList.push[mailRecCount, 2] = "Needed";`  You are using brackets with `push`.  You can't do that.  You must use parenthesis.  And I don't know why you are using the assignment operator.  It seems like you are trying to add elements to an array in the same way that you'd add a `key/value` element pair to an object.  An array and an object don't use the same syntax.  [Link - JavaScript - Push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: Thank you. Let me take a look. I think that is a remnant of a previous failed attempt that I did not replace. I used the assignment operator because in a previous language that was how it was done. Language hopping has my brain confused. So then if I wanted to push to a 3rd column would I use `mailRecList(eName[r],"Needed","Needed");` ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the inner array and then push that into your 2D array. As this updated snippet of your code shows:

```js
function fillMailRecList() {

  var eName =      ['Ignore1', 'Ignore2', 'Fred', 'Bill',   'Sam']
  var eAcceptNDA = ['',        '',        '',     'Ignore', '']
  
  var mailRecList = []
  var mailRecListItem = []
  var mailRecCount = 0

  // Extract the users who need review
  for (var r = 2; r < eName.length; r++) {
  
    if (eName[r] !== "") {
    
      if (eAcceptNDA[r] === "") {
      
//        mailRecList[mailRecCount, 0] = eName[r]
        
        mailRecListItem.push(eName[r])
        
        if (eAcceptNDA[r] == "") {
          
//          mailRecList[mailRecCount, 1] = "Needed"

        mailRecListItem.push("Needed")
          
        } else { 
          
//          mailRecList[mailRecCount, 1] = "----"; 

          mailRecListItem.push("----")
        }
        
        // mailRecListItem is a reference to the array that will be used
        // again next time around, so you need to take a new copy of it
        // to keep. This also has the effect of clearing the working array
        // ready for the next loop
        mailRecList.push(mailRecListItem.splice(0, mailRecListItem.length))        
      }      
    }    
  }
  
  Logger.log(mailRecList) // [[Fred, Needed], [Sam, Needed]]
}
```

You can see this running [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1WY7ZvoVUROoR78aJL4_4ZQ_Xa0xkDHRq6N63PUThFgUCFspclqtudXJA/edit?template=default&usp=drive_web&folder=0BxRtIprIrwuzQklkaTJRSTVRTW8).